How to write Unit Test Case for singleton class kotlin
I want to release current instance but that not working here is there any easier way to handle it.
I have a class -> DownloadManager which is singleton
And I have a @Before test which always execute unit test case and I am initially this DownloadManager please find below class example.
@Before
fun setup() {
    sut = spyk(DownloadManager()
}


You should release the instance by using a tearDown() method,
@After
    fun tearDown() {
        sut.close()
    }

It will ensuree that the downloadManager instance is properly closed after the test method, thus avoiding potential resource leaks.

try not working

@After fun tearDown() {     try {         sut.close()     } catch (e: Exception) {         Log.e("tearDown", "Error closing sut", e)     } }
Log exceptions to see if any errors are occurring during the cleanup process.
